# Make Amazon S3 files available only to logged in users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I make the files in Amazon S3 accessible only to logged in users? I use PHP for my website. Static files are stored in Amazon S3. Only users logged in to my website should be able to access the files in Amazon cloud. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use signed URL that are generated by your application based on users logins:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_QSAuth.html