# S3 file availability and permits

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, tomcat7, vaadin

I want a file stored in an S3 bucket to be available only for users of a specific web application located on an EC2 instance.

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028777/make-amazon-s3-files-available-only-to-logged-in-users), but it leads to a deleted link...

It is also explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4), but I don't know how to implement the solution...I'm supposed to include this code somewhere:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originated from www.example.com and example.com",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code of your's is aws security policy.....

You need to do the following things:

```
Step1: Create a IAM user from AWS Dashboard -> Users -> Create New Users.

Step2: Create a policy for your bucket from AWS Dashboard -> Policies -> Get Started -> Create Policy.

Step3: Attach the policy created in Step2 to the user created in step1.
```

Now your bucket will be accessible only to the user you created with the policies you specified.

Since your policy has a rule

```
"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]
```

the bucket will be accessible only from the urls you have specified.

Comment: Thanks for your help @WisdmLabs ... I created a user "user1" and a policy to grant access to a specificic bucket (the "policy document" code was created automatically when I chose the bucket) . Then I attached the policy to the user...I tried to create extra permits to my bucket by looking for the policy but I couldn't find it from there...Is that it?